# Getting the same value from a pH Probe

Tags: arduino, wiring, hardware, probe, ph

I am totally new and looking for some advice, please.

I am trying to connect a [pH Probe](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2019/11/measure-ph-with-a-low-cost-arduino-ph-sensor-board/) (PH-4502C) to a Wemos D1. I believe to have wired this up all correctly, I have wired the PO pin to the A0 pin, the GND pin to the GND, and the VCC to both the 5 & 3.3 V pins.

[image]

I have tried debugging the code.

[image]

But as you can see I get the same result no matter what the fluid the probe is dipped in. I have tried turning both of the potts, but the returned value is the same. Being new to this I am not sure if this is a faulty probe or I have done something wrong. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is your probe working?  Has it been left to dry out at some point in its life?  It may not be detecting changes.  Which "fluids" are you using?

Comment: You said you wired "VCC to both the 5 & 3.3 V pins". That can't be right. Double-check this. Also, you need to provide a link to the **manufacturer's data sheet** for the probe.

Comment: Try and connect another analog signal to A0 (without the pH probe) and see if you get a response.

Comment: Shouldnt this be better suited for Robotics SE?

Comment: "the VCC to both the 5 & 3.3 V pins." - if I understand this correctly (you connected both *at the same time*, then you've shorted the 3v3 pin to 5v. This may be the cause of your issue, or it may have caused damage to your microcontroller board.

Comment: No sorry for the misunderstanding, I have connected to the 5v and then tried the 3.3v

Comment: I have also tried to attach something else to the A) pin and got some values, https://embeddeddev369484215.files.wordpress.com/2021/01/datasheet_ph-4502c.pdf is the datasheet I have been working from

Comment: I would eliminate the arduino from the equation and just read PO with a multimeter first. Your probe or the PCB may be defective.

Comment: Also confirm that the Ph PCB is getting power, and maybe try messing with the pots as a last resort.

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96653/ph-4502c-ph-sensor-calibration-and-adc-using-mcp3008-pcf8591-and-ads1115/96654#96654

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have been waiting for a multimeter to be delivered... So it seems that if I connect up a multimeter I am getting the correct 2.5v out when I short the as per the instructions. However I seem to be reading a completely different voltage when I try and read the A0 pin.

Comment: I am using a wemos d1 board if I am missing a step, Thanks again